# How do i decode text of a pdf file using python

Tags: string, pdf, text, encoding, decoding

I have been trying to decode a pdf file using python and the data is as below:
BT
/F2 8.8 Tf
1 0 0 1 36.85 738.3 Tm
0 g
0 G
[(A)31(c)-44(c)-44(o)-79(u)11(n)-79(t)5( )] TJ
ET

How do I make sense of this???

[(A)31(c)-44(c)-44(o)-79(u)11(n)-79(t)5( )] is of what type???

Comment: *"How do I make sense of this???"* - how about reading the pdf specification? That would be ISO 32000. A copy of the older part 1, ISO 32000-1, can be downloaded at https://Adobe.com/go/pdfreference

Comment: (A)31(c)-44(c)-44(o)-79(u)11(n)-79(t)5( ) is of what type???

Comment: It's the content of an array containing strings and numbers.

Comment: is that encoded??

Comment: *"is that encoded??"* - What do you mean? It's completely normal syntax of PDF objects. It's actually a fairly simple example as the encoding of the strings appears to be ASCII-like.

Answer (score 0):

`BT /F2 8.8 Tf 1 0 0 1 36.85 738.3 Tm 0 g 0 G [(A)31(c)-44(c)-44(o)-79(u)11(n)-79(t)5( )] TJ ET`

Is normal plain ASCII text, thus everyday, decoded binary as text.

Your question is
**Q)** How do I make sense of this??? `[(A)31(c)-44(c)-44(o)-79(u)11(n)-79(t)5( )]`

**A)** Always look at the context

```
BT  = B(egin) T(ext)
/F2 = use F(ont) 2 for encoding (whatever that is)
8.8 = units of height (if un-modified those could be 8.8 full unscaled DTP points, 
      but beware, point size does not necessarily correspond to any measurement
      of the size of the letters on the printed page.)
... Mainly T(ransform )m(atrix) e.g. placement
[   = start a string group
(A) = literal(y) "A"
31  = Kern next character (+ is usually) left wise by 31 units where units (is usually) 1/1440 inch or 17.639 µm
(c) = the next glyph literal that needs to be etched on screen or paper
-44 is push the two x (c) apart by 44 units
(c)
...
] Tj ET  = Close Group, T(exte)j(ect) E(nd) T(ext)
```

So there we have it somewhere on the page (first or last word or any time in between) but at that time somewhere, most likely top Left, there is one continuous selectable plain text string that **audibly sounds like a word in a human language = "Account", with an extra spacebar literal (that's actually un-necessary for a PDF, it will print that and any other "word" good enough without one.)

Why did I say sounds and not "looks like" is because those "literal" characters are not the ones presented they are the encoded names of glyphs.

Hear :-) is how they could look like using /F2 if it was set to different glyph font such as use emojis or other Dings, so `A` is BC but `c` is a checkbox `u` is underground `t` is train but audibly all ink, is just an `Account` of which graphics to use.

[image]